# Нужно в массиве найти количество уникальных значений и добавить их в другой массив. С#

Tags: c#, массивы, словари

```
        Dictionary<float,int> Chastota = new Dictionary<float, int>(N);
        foreach (var element in Massive)
        {
            Chastota.TryGetValue(element, out var count);
            Chastota[element] = ++count;
        }
        var t = Chastota.ToArray();
```

вот мой кусок кода в котором я нахожу уникальные элементы. В последующем нужно работать с их количеством, вот только как? Пример работы: массив из 5 элементов 4,4,5,5,6. Количество уникальных - 3, а парный массив будет 425261. Мне нужно отсюда вычленить в другой массив 2,2,1

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите в итоге сделать.  
Простой способ найти уникальные все элементы - метод `Distinct` (должно быть открыто простраснство имён `System.Linq`).  
Чтобы на выходе получился массив нужно сделать `var uniqueValues = array.Distinct().ToArray()`.  
Количество элементов массива можно посмотреть без потерь - `var unqueCount = uniqueValues.Length`.

Comment: почему float? Вы в курсе, что это числа с ограниченной точностью?

Comment: Внимательнее прочитал ваш код. Правильно понял, что вам  в итоге нужно получить **частоту**, с которой элементы встречаются в массиве? И вы хотите получить на выходе массив, в котором за элементом массива следует его частота, так?

Comment: Упс. Мужики, не увидел, что тут комментарии есть. float - мне хватит, тут идет речь о сотых.  Да, совершенно верно, просто я только такой вариант получения уникальных значений знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Можете поступить таким образом:

```
// dict = это любой словарь, в том числе ваш "Chastota"
var items = dict.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
var freqs = dict.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Почитайте про [Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/), там очень много удобных фич.

Comment: И что получается? Два массива: один с ключом, а второй с значением этого ключа?

Comment: Да. Опять же, ту могу посоветовать почитать IEnumerable и его реализацию в IDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте у `Dictionary` свойство [`Values`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=net-6.0):

```
var result = Chastota.Values.ToArray(); // В result будет лежать [2, 2, 1]
```